# How to Password Char a Column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, password-protection

I am trying to password char a column when loading in a table.

***Code below loads the table.***

```
//Fills out Student table
private void loadStudentTable()
{
    SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
    conn2.Open();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmdDatabase2 = new SqlCommand("Select * from Student", conn2);
        SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda2.SelectCommand = cmdDatabase2;
        DataTable dbdataset2 = new DataTable();
        sda2.Fill(dbdataset2);
        BindingSource bSource2 = new BindingSource();
        bSource2.DataSource = dbdataset2;
        studentGridView.DataSource = bSource2;
        sda2.Update(dbdataset2);
        studentGridView.Columns[0].Width = 92;
        studentGridView.Columns[1].Width = 200;
        studentGridView.Columns[2].Width = 180;
        studentGridView.Columns[3].Width = 180;
        studentGridView.Columns[4].Width = 170;
        studentGridView.Columns[5].Width = 170;
        studentGridView.Columns[6].Width = 130;                        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    conn2.Close();
}
```

I am trying to password char the `studentGridView.Columns[5].Width = 170;` column.

Any help or ideas?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @S.Akbari how do i show it in password cases for instance ******

Comment: You mean that you want to show the column 5 as password char?

Comment: @S.Akbari yes thats exactly what i would like to happen. please

Comment: Are you going to allow copying of the grid?  Why put the password in there at all, if it's going to be obscured?  Why even pull it out of the database (and how are you storing it, so that it's not easily compromised by, say, a developer putting it into a grid and allowing the grid to be copied?)?

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet calm down, its just a small personal project to understand c# more.

Comment: Pretty calm, here - just don't think security should be an afterthought, is all, and if you get in the habit of it being something you leave out, you'll leave it out when it matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event of your `DataGridView` like this

```
private void studentGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (gv_Input.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index == 5 && e.Value != null)
    {
        studentGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Tag = e.Value;
        e.Value = new String('*', e.Value.ToString().Length);
    }
}
```